# Kotlin: SensorManager in ForegroundService killed when Application is off

Tags: android, kotlin, foreground-service

I put `sensor manager` in `foreground service` not to be killed when app is off.

```
class MyService : Service(), SensorEventListener {

    private lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager
    private lateinit var step_sensor: Sensor

    private val db = Firebase.firestore
    private val userDB = Firebase.firestore.collection("users")
    private val diaryDB = Firebase.firestore.collection("diary")
    private val userId = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid

    companion object {
        var todayTotalStepCount: MutableLiveData<Int>? = MutableLiveData()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()


        // 오늘 걸음수 초기화
        userDB.document("$userId").get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            var todayStepCountFromDB = document.getLong("todayStepCount") ?: 0
            todayTotalStepCount?.value = todayStepCountFromDB.toInt()
        }

        sensorManager =
            applicationContext?.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        step_sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR)

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, step_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI)

    }


    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
//        TODO("Not yet implemented")
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
    }


    override fun onSensorChanged(stepEvent: SensorEvent?) {
        Log.d("결과", "$stepEvent")

}
```

And I link this `service` to `fragment`.

```
    var startService = Intent(activity, MyService::class.java)
    activity?.startService(startService)
```

It works well in foreground and background either. However when I kill app, it stops. I'm a newbie in Kotlin.

**Please help me with detail code.**

***Thank you!***

Comment: "However when I kill app, it stops" -- you might want to explain in detail what you mean by "kill app".

Comment: well when app is off, it doesn't track step count any more.